# How can I remove conflicting DNF package after a repo remove?

Tags: reinstall, repository, dnf, software-conflict

I removed a repo that I was not using anymore. I thought I did things properly by removing all packages provided by that repo before removing the `.repo` file with `rm`. Alas, it seems that it wasn't the case and PHP hasn't been correctly uninstalled.

Now, if I type `sudo dnf install php`, I have the following result:

```
Erreur : 
 Problème: conflicting requests
  - package php-7.4.16-1.fc33.x86_64 requires php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.16-1.fc33, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package php-7.4.11-1.fc33.x86_64 requires php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.11-1.fc33, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package php-common-7.4.16-1.fc33.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package php-common-7.4.11-1.fc33.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
(essayez d’ajouter « --skip-broken » pour ignorer les paquets non installables)
```

The note in French at the end tells me to try to add `--skip-broken`, but it doesn't work with it either, as it simply ignores PHP installation.

I guess that I have to remove `php-common` in order to reinstall it properly, but `sudo dnf remove php-common` tells me that there is no match.

How can I remove `php` and `php-common` in order to reinstall them properly?